# How to display only 3 columns of a table but allow side-scrolling to see the rest? (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using a TableLayout right now and I'd like to have a table that has x amount of columns, but only shows 3 at a time on-screen.

I'd like the layout to be side-scrollable to provide access to the rest.

How can I do this? I'd like it to scale to all resolutions - if it was HTML, I'd simply have a width of 33% each but apparently that's not possible on Android.

So far all I have accomplished is 4 columns displaying at once, and I don't know where to go next to push one of them off-screen.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I need to maintain my table layout and cells because I need borders between certain cells and not between others.

Screenshot of what I'm trying to do: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Belj4.png)

Answer (score 0):

to wanted 3 column in a table view.

you should take columnview and get the row and column and show this column with tostring() method.

```
for(int i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
            String row  = rows[i];
            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
            final String[] cols = row.split(";");

            Handler handler = null;

            for (int j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {

                final String col = cols[j];                                 
                final TextView columsView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                columsView.setText(String.format("%7s", col));                              
                tableRow.addView(columsView);
```

String.format("%7s", col));

in this `"%(put 20 or near by this)S"`

take the table layout under the horizontal scrol view.

try this it will work.

Comment: I just edited the question to clarify... I don't think I can maintain my formatting if I use this approach because I need borders between every cell (two cells per column) and every other row, like this:

[screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/Belj4.png)